# Converting c# data from entity framework to a valid json type

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

i have below method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data= (dynamic)null;
        using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            data= context.MyObject.Where(i=> i.TypeId == 1).OrderBy(k => k.Name).Select(w => new
            {
                description = w.Description
            }).ToList();       
        }

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

so I want to convert the data correctly into a json object, but i am not sure if i am doing correctly. This data returned should be used in a javascript.

I have google a lot and i have found example like below, maybe I should do a similar thing, but i do not know how:

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
               {
                   { "emailSend", textBox1.Text },
                   { "toEmail", textBox2.Text }
               };

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);
MessageBox.Show(json);
```

Comment: Use `Newtonsoft.Json`!

Comment: Your code will return `Json`? your calling `Json()` in your controller. This will convert your object into Json. No need for anything else.

Comment: I should be return json data but i am not sure if i am done it correctly from the controller.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` is a windows method and won't work in ASP.Net also

Comment: `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` is the correct way

Comment: @Liam it was an example, i am not using messagebox.show, i only want to be sure if by doing what i am doing json() it is correct or not.

Comment: @Johan Ok! many thanks! this is whant I want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using any `JavaScriptSerializer`. Just return `Json` as you already did. That's the correct approach of sending JSON to the client from a controller action. The model you passed as parameter will automatically be serialized into a JSON string by the framework. Also you don't need to be setting `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` because your controller action is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute meaning that it can only be invoked with the POST verb and never with GET. This is required only for controller actions that are returning JsonResult and which can be invoked with the GET verb.